# How to get syslogd/klogd to append to syslog after reboot instead of overwriting?

Tags: kernel, logs, syslog, busybox

After a reboot or crash, the syslog does not save any messages from the previous session. What should I do to tell syslogd/klogd to append to syslog instead of overwriting every session? I feel I am missing something obvious.

Some background on my system:

- Distribution: **Yocto (poky) with busybox**
- Method of launching klogd/syslogd: **init**
- Starting configs/scrips klogd/syslogd uses: **/etc/syslog-startup.conf and /etc/init.d/syslog**

**/etc/syslog-startup.conf**

```
# This configuration file is used by the busybox syslog init script,
# /etc/init.d/syslog[.busybox] to set syslog configuration at start time.

DESTINATION=file        # log destinations (buffer file remote)
LOGFILE=/var/log/syslog     # where to log (file)
REMOTE=loghost:514      # where to log (syslog remote)
REDUCE=no           # reduce-size logging
DROPDUPLICATES=no       # whether to drop duplicate log entries
ROTATESIZE=100          # rotate log if grown beyond X [kByte]
ROTATEGENS=3            # keep X generations of rotated logs
BUFFERSIZE=64           # size of circular buffer [kByte]
FOREGROUND=no           # run in foreground (don't use!)
LOGLEVEL=8          # local log level (between 1 and 8)
```

**/etc/init.d/syslog**

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             sysklogd
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $time
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $time
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    System logger
### END INIT INFO

set -e

if [ -f /etc/syslog-startup.conf ]; then
    . /etc/syslog-startup.conf
    LOG_LOCAL=0
    LOG_REMOTE=0
    for D in $DESTINATION; do
        if [ "$D" = "buffer" ]; then
            SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -C$BUFFERSIZE"
            LOG_LOCAL=1
        elif [ "$D" = "file" ]; then
            if [ -n "$LOGFILE" ]; then
                SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -O $LOGFILE"
            fi
            if [ -n "$ROTATESIZE" ]; then
                SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -s $ROTATESIZE"
            fi
            if [ -n "$ROTATEGENS" ]; then
                SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -b $ROTATEGENS"
            fi
            LOG_LOCAL=1
        elif [ "$D" = "remote" ]; then
            SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -R $REMOTE"
            LOG_REMOTE=1
        fi
    done
    if [ "$LOG_LOCAL" = "1" -a "$LOG_REMOTE" = "1" ]; then
        SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -L"
    fi
    if [ "$REDUCE" = "yes" ]; then
        SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -S"
    fi
    if [ "$DROPDUPLICATES" = "yes" ]; then
        SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -D"
    fi
    if [ -n "$LOGLEVEL" ]; then
        SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -l $LOGLEVEL"
    fi
else
    # default: log to 16K shm circular buffer
    SYSLOG_ARGS="-C"
fi

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting syslogd/klogd: "
    start-stop-daemon -S -b -n syslogd -a /sbin/syslogd -- -n $SYSLOG_ARGS
    start-stop-daemon -S -b -n klogd -a /sbin/klogd -- -n
    echo "done"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping syslogd/klogd: "
    start-stop-daemon -K -n syslogd
    start-stop-daemon -K -n klogd
    echo "done"
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: syslog { start | stop | restart }" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Hmmmm....I'm confused, why would you think that after a reboot any information would be left from the previous boot.  This doesn't make sense.  When the system is normally shutdown, all buffers should be cleared and thus whatever is available at that point will be logged until the syslog logger process is killed off.

Comment: Because on my other machines it keeps messages from previous sessions. Yes, all buffers should be cleared, but syslog seems to be a log file and not a buffer like dmesg, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems /var/log/ directory was redirected to /var/volatile/log/ at boot which is mounted as tempfs so the data wouldn't be saved across a reboot/crash. Commenting out the line that mounts /var/volatile/ directory as tmpfs in the /etc/fstab file seems to have worked.